# Upload file to core hosted server returns 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to upload a file to the server, as I have already done in my project. However, I keep getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error on catch.

I've copied over the exact code I've used to upload another file, and checked that the file content is there when pushing it to the server. But I can't even hit any of my breakpoints on the server.

```cs
private void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    _files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    fileNames = files.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file is not null)
        {
            _filename = file.Name;
            _files.Add(file);
        }
    }
}

private async Task Upload()
{
    if (_files.FirstOrDefault() is null)
        return;

    _loading = true;

    var file = _files.First();
    using (var ms = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size))
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
        content.Add(new StreamContent(ms, Convert.ToInt32(file.Size)), "csv", _filename);                

        Interceptor.RegisterEvent();

        await Repository.AddMultiAsset(content, ClientUser.Email);

        Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.TopCenter;
        Snackbar.Add("Files uploaded successfully!", Severity.Success);

        _files.Clear();
        fileNames.Clear();
    }

    _loading = false;
}
```

And then the Repo handling api calls:

```cs
public async Task AddMultiAsset(MultipartFormDataContent content, string user)
{            
    try
    {
        using (var response = await _client.PostAsync($"api/admin/upload?user={user}", content))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        };

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The catch is where I get the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error, although I know the httpclient, user variable, or MultipartFormDataContent content are all not null.

I can't see any network calls in the dev tools either so it's not even making a request to the server.

I'm at a lost as to what to do here, I have another function exactly the same just pointing to a different controller that works perfectly.

Comment: Can you add the HTML of your Blazor?, I mean here not the code behind.

Comment: Not enough info here to debug this. Try to reduce to a [mre]

Comment: This might be linked to this [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39087). [Fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/39075) in release 6.0.2.